# Where to store Google Service Account Key while using Google Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Using Google Firebase Functions as a backend of the small application.

Functions are accessing to the Firestore and Realtime database, therefore they need `service account credentials` file.

On the other hand, I'm trying to automate the deployment of the functions using Github Actions.

Currently I places the credentials file inside the repository. I know that it's not secure.

What is the proper way of storing `service account credentials` file in this case?

Comment: You don't need service account key file to access services from your backend. You can use the Firebase function identity with the Google Cloud Client libraries

Comment: what do you mean by "Firebase function identity"?

Comment: When you deploy a firebase function, you deploy, in fact a Cloud Functions. The Cloud Functions have, by default a service account (compute engine default service account). But you can override that default service account (with Cloud Functions, I don't know how to do that with firebase). So now, you can have a look to the doc: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Can you post this solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase projects, are, in effect, Google Cloud Platform projects.
More specifically, when you create a Firebase project, [an associated Google Cloud Platform project is created for it](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts#:%7E:text=others%20are%20added%20via%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20project%20associated%20with%20your%20Firebase%20project.).

Therefore the process for storing credentials is the same as in [Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production), which is to say in a file, somewhere relatively safe.
This file should be accessible to your Function if it is required, and should either have its path specified as part of an environment variable or explicitly declared in code.

You are already storing it the proper way, because the improper way would be to insert the contents of the `JSON` file directly into code.
To prevent others from seeing the contents of the `JSON` file, simply set the respository as private.